# Alternative to calling a static method via an instance

Tags: java, static, joptionpane

```
JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane( );
jop.showMessageDialog(“This is never done”);
```

I'm told that this is done in poor taste.  I mean it works, but apparently a "pro" would not do it thus as showMessageDialog is static.  Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: If the method is static call it as such. `ClassName.staticMethod` => `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog...`

Comment: any good IDE would tell you that, no need for a pro.

Comment: btw, the reason it's in poor taste is that it's confusing: it looks like the method is invoked on an instance, when in fact it's not. A classic example: `Thread t = getSomeThread(); t.sleep(1000);` looks like it's making the `t` thread sleep for a second, right? Nope! `sleep` is a static method which causes the _current_ thread to sleep.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `static` method can be invoked without a reference to an instance:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("This is never done");
```

---

Actually, these line:

```
JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane();
jop.showMessageDialog("This is never done");
```

will be converted at compile time to:

```
JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("This is never done");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating an object to simply call its static method?  There's no reason for it.
`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("This is never done");` is all you need.