# Use Of Static variables in java?

Tags: java

I mean we know that Static members should only belongs to the Class,and not part of the any object created from the class . but we can also access static methods via objects right? lets say `getInstaceCount()` is the static member of `Class CharStack`.
for example I can create object here and access Static member of CharStack :

```
CharStack stack1 = new Charstack(10);// declaring object
int count1 = stack1.getinstanceCount();//accessing Static member with the object
```

so above I can also access the static member of Charstack with object stack1,so my doubt is what is the exact use of Static member if its even accessible by its object ?similarly why instance variable of a class is not accessible by Class ?

Comment: Well, there's no way to find which instance variable you meant via the class.  There could be no instance variables, or there could be an infinite number of them (up to the limits of system memory, of course).

Comment: read it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: You _can_ access them that way, but you shouldn't; it's confusing, because people will assume it's an instance method.

Comment: Accessing static members via class instance is just a convenience provided to java developers. The compiler converts it to Class.staticMeber upon compilation. Personally I don't like it. Can't understand why the community requested this feature.

Comment: See also my comment at this possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23501156/1076640

Comment: @MikayilAbdullayev Actually, the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.1) says *"The Primary expression is evaluated, and the result is discarded"*, so it is not (necessarily) converted by the compiler. Any side-effect of the left-hand side of the `.` operator is executed. --- Also, I don't think the community requested this feature. I believe it's been that way from the start, so it's the language designers you should blame.

Answer (score 9):

A `static` method doesn't make any sense with respect of a specific instance of a class.

The fact that invoking a `static` method on an instance is allowed shouldn't fool you: it just a design error of Java language which makes no sense.

- A `static` method doesn't have a `this` reference so it makes no sense to be able to invoke it on a specific instance.
- in addition a `static` method is not polymorphic so in any case you can't exploit this fact by calling it on an instance

Short story: `static` methods make sense in certain situations, but you should always call them through the class, eg `CharStakc.getInstanceCount()` to clarify their intended behavior, **since being allowed to invoke them through instances is just a bad choice which shouldn't be allowed at all**.

Comment: Good IDE's will warn you about non-static access to static fields and methods. Always use an IDE!!

Comment: Yes, most IDEs do, and most of them should also be able to force treating it as an error (which is, IMHO)

Comment: @Jack thank you :) for your answer..it clarified my little confusion :D

Answer (score 1):

> similarly why instance variable is not accessible by Class ?

Say you have this class:

```
 class Foo{
    public static Bar barStatic;
    public Bar barInstance;
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Foo foo=new Foo();
       Bar barInstance=Foo.barInstance;//case 1
       Bar barStatic=foo.barStatic;// case 2
       .....
    }
 }
```

Now in case 1 you want to access some object's instance variable. But which object? One, more or no objects of the class Foo might be in the heap. But based on what should the runtime decide which object to choose (if one exists of course). 
But in case 2, even though you say `foo.barStatic` compiler is "smart enough" to know that foo is an instance of Foo and interprets your `foo.barStatic` as `Foo.barStatic` when you compile the code. I definitely don't like this design, it's confusing. So, you should know that everything is fine under the hood, it's just during code design it doesn't complain although as others have noted, good IDE's will warn you to follow the preferred `Foo.barStatic` way.

Comment: hoo yeah... :) thank you @Mikayil..yeah its seems legit :) clarified :)

Answer (score 0):

The static variable gets memory **only once** in class area at the time of class loading.
It makes your program **memory efficient** (i.e it saves memory).
The static variable can be used to refer the common property of all objects (that is not unique for each object) e.g. company name of employees,college name of students etc.