# Output of this code is 10, why?

Tags: java

Why is this giving me 10 as output, rather than an error?

```
public class A {
    static int a = m1();

    static int m1(){
        return 10;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a1 = null;
        System.out.println(a1.a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would it give an error?

Comment: "wanna"?  You might care to use real English words and not slang. This isn't yahoo groups.

Comment: Please, don't use snippets for Java.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501156/alternative-to-calling-a-static-method-via-an-instance and many others...

Answer (score 2):

Because compiler is  so intelligent here,it basically replaces

```
 System.out.println(a1.a);
```

with

```
System.out.println(A.a); //The name of your class 'A'
```

Comment: On a side note: I still wonder why the Java even allows the notation `a1.a` here, as it only leads to confusion to call a static method/variable like that...

Answer (score 0):

Because `a` is a static variable, so the reference to `A a1` isn't dereferenced. You might want to write `A.a` instead to make the code more intuitive.